# Object C static variable memory question

Tags: objective-c, memory, static

As you know, we define a static variable parameter in Object c,

what I am concerning, how to map this static Object variable from memory management view.

for example

```
@interface classA:NSObject
+ (id) getInstance;
@end

static ClassA staticObject = nil;
@implementation ClassA
 + (id){
      if(staticObject)
         staticObject = [doinitStuff];
      return staticObject   
 }
@end
```

now the question is: who is responsible to hold staticObject memory,
when it will be released.

what I am thinking:

Runtime OS will monitor application, and only when application really exit, this memory will be released.
from RUNtime view, it is retained and count = 1;//just 1

any thought would be great appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no different than any other variable.  If you want it to stick around, `retain` it.  If not, don't (or, if retained, release/autorelease it).

There is non need to release memory on exit of an application.  When your app terminates, all resources will be reaped regardless.

Comment: Thanks bbum, I am still confused,since normally, when we do init, always do alloc, and then return it. for example: staticObject = [ClassA alloc]init]; memory was allocated, right?

Comment: @Jeff, correct. staticObject now has a retain count of at least 1. It is now correct and will live for the life of the program. bbum's point is that if you want it to live, just make sure you keep a retain, either through alloc, copy or retain.

Comment: To elaborate on bbum's comment: please *don't* release memory on application exit. It just slows down quitting and breaks sudden termination support for no gain.